# VBA:Selenium: run time error on Foreach statement?

Tags: vba, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting an error "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Below is my coding,

```
Dim webs, web As Object
Set webs = driverg.findElementByCssSelector("*[class^='title-link id-track-click']")

**For Each web In webs**
Debug.Print web.Text
Next web
```

When program starts in foreach, I'm getting this error.

Is there any another method looping Web-element as I have tried a lot, but I can't solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You've defined webs as a Variant

By putting them on same line it doesn't default to the declaration at the end

Define them on their own separate lines

```
Dim webs As Object 
Dim web As Object
```

Or if that's not what you intended and web is an array then use

```
Dim webs As Object 
Dim web As Variant
```

> EDIT - check docs

According to docs - it only returns the first element - so I'm not sure why you're doing a "For each"

> Type: IWebElement The first IWebElement matching the criteria.

Comment: I want find all element for class  Equal"*[class^='title-link id-track-click'], can tell me how to find all element and  explain me foreach statement still not working. I using VBA with Selenium webdriver

Answer (score 0):

I have changed findElementByCssSelector into findElementsByCssSelector, as findElementByCssSelector return only one element hence that for each not wroking but when changed into findElemenstByCssSelector, getting working.

I have changed below line

```
driverg.findElementByCssSelector("*[class^='title-link id-track-click']")
```

to

```
driverg.findElementsByCssSelector("*[class^='title-link id-track-click']")
```